# Mapping of values in python with loop instead of if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, text, mapping, tuples

How can I improve this function?

It should be good to have all of the search lines in a file or so. It is important that they are in this order. Can i use while or?

```
def findlarm(text):
    """
    Lookijng for a lable to put on map
    :param text:
    :return:

    """
    if text.lower().find('brand i byggnad industri') >= 0:
        label = 'Brand i byggnad industri'
    elif text.lower().encode('utf8').find('trafikolycka påkörd person') >= 0:
        label = 'Trafikolycka påkörd person'
    elif text.lower().find('trafikolycka') >= 0:
        label = 'Trafikolycka'
    elif text.lower().find('brand i byggnad') >= 0:
        label = 'Brand i byggnad'
    elif text.lower().encode('utf8').find('röklukt') >= 0:
        label = 'Röklukt'
    elif text.lower().encode('utf8').find('Brand ute - terräng Gräsbrand') >= 0:
        label = 'Gräsbrand'
    elif text.lower().encode('utf8').find('Utsläpp farligt ämne') >= 0:
        label = 'Utsläpp farligt ämne'
    elif text.lower().encode('utf8').find('brand ute - övrigt') >= 0:
        label = 'Brand ute - övrigt'
    elif text.lower().encode('utf8').find('sjukvårdslarm') >= 0:
        label = 'Sjukvårdslarm'
    elif text.lower().encode('utf8').find('passning') >= 0:
        label = 'Passning station'
    elif text.lower().find('annat') >= 0:
        label = 'Annat larm'
    elif text.lower().find('skogsbrand') >= 0:
        label = 'Skogsbrand'
    elif text.lower().find('drunkning') >= 0:
        label = 'Drunkning'
    elif text.lower().find('fartyg') >= 0:
        label = 'Fartyg/Båtolycka'
    elif text.lower().find('ivpa') >= 0:
        label = 'IVPA'
    elif text.lower().find('automatiskt brandlarm') >= 0:
        label = 'Aut Brandlarm'
    elif text.lower().find('sjukdomsfall') >= 0:
        label = 'Sjukdomsfall'
    elif text.lower().find('brand') >= 0:
        label = 'Brand'
    elif text.lower().find('trauma') >= 0:
        label = 'Trauma'
    elif text.lower().encode('utf8').find('Järnväg - påkörd person') >= 0:
        label = 'Järnväg - påkörd person'
    elif text.lower().encode('utf8').find('övrigt ambulansassistans') >= 0:
        label = 'Ambulansassistans'
    else:
        label = 'Okänt larm'
    return label
```

Comment: You could make a dict of keywords and labels then iterate through it and if a keyword is found set label to dict[keyword].

Comment: To quote: "It is important that they are in this order."

Answer (score 2):

Make a list of pairs (tuples) with the strings to be found and the corresponding labels.

Then loop through that list until a match is found, pick the corresponding label and break (or return it directly). Here is example code:

```
def findlarm(text):
    labels = [('foo', 'bar'), ('hans', 'wurst')]

    test = text.lower() #.encode('utf8')
    for l in labels:
        if test.find(l[0]) >= 0:
            return l[1]

    return 'Okänt larm'
```

I commented out the encode() call as I am using Python 3.

Comment: But with a dictionary you lose the order! It was indicated by OP that the order is important.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a for loop, but I think this is a good place to use a `for-in` loop, along with the string method `capitalize()`:

```
mylist = [
    'brand i byggnad industri',
    'trafikolycka påkörd person',
    # etc.
]

label = None
for term in mylist:
    if text.lower().encode('utf8').find(term) >= 0:
        label = term.capitalize()
        break
return label  # returns None if none of the terms were found
```

EDIT: As another user pointed out, not all of your labels are capitalized versions of the text to find. If you need different labels, then the other answer is better.

Comment: It would be better to initialize `label` with `label = 'Okänt larm'` since it is the `else` value. And to call `text.lower().encode('utf8')` once before the for loop. No need to repeat that call over and over again.

Comment: Wow, so many answers in just one day. Thanks all. I ve just take a quick look and i think the last answer looks most promising. I will try maybe later tonight.